# How to get items in a SharePoint list

Tags: list, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I am using PowerShell.
I want to get information on **all columns** of all items in the SharePoint list.
However, when using the "Get-PnPListItem" command, only the "ID", "Title", and "GUID could be obtained.
Is there a way to get the information of the column I have added to the SharePoint list myself?

Comment: Have a look at [Get-PnPListItem Not returning all the Fields](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/256015/get-pnplistitem-not-returning-all-the-fields/256020)

Comment: Thank you!
We succeeded by referring to the provided page! !